# Layered Navigation not showing Attributes

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, attribute-set

I have a Magento install which has several attributes in attributes sets, but they are not showing up in the layered navigation on the left hand side of the page.

I have made sure that the attributes are set as drop downs, they have been set to 'Filterable (with results)' and to show on the front end, but they are still not showing up.

I have tried deleting the attributes, re-adding them, re-inputting the attribute data on to the products and still no luck.

Its a strange problem because it works for some attributes but not others, yet the ones that are showing are set up exactly the same as the ones that aren't.

Has anyone had any problems like this before?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I assume all products have the same value for these not showing attributes, haven't they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides the attribute settings, you also need to check each category. I.E. the **category needs to be anchored.**

While editing the category, go to the `Display Settings` tab and check that `Is Anchor` is set to `yes`.